# Do notifications currently in beta work in testing?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to push a notification to an unpublished Action in testing. I'm using a snippet I found here

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates

In particular

```
function send(err, tokens) {

 var notif, payload;

 notif = { userNotification: { title: 'Commuter Alert' },
           target: { userId: userId, intent: intent } };

 console.log( JSON.stringify(notif) );

 payload = { 'auth': { 'bearer': tokens.access_token },
             'json': true,
             'body': { 'customPushMessage': notif, 'isInSandbox': false } };

 request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send',
                payload,
                  responseComplete);

}
```

I get a 400/Bad Request response with a message of

Invalid user id for target.

The notification stringified looks like this:

```
{"userNotification":{"title":"Commuter Alert"},"target":{"userId":"APhe68Has7QXmEFRmxhe9MGcLK2t","intent":"www.whereismybus.xyz.intent.NOTIFY_QUERY"}}
```

and the userId that it shows is the same as the one that shows on the request tab in the simulator

```
"user": {
    "userId": "APhe68Has7QXmEFRmxhe9MGcLK2t",
    "permissions": [
      "UPDATE"
    ], ...
```

To my nearsighted eyes, it looks like the userId is OK. Anyone?

EDIT: It turns out that the error message is correct and so is the code. When I try testing the Action under a different identity the POST completes with a 200/OK status. What is slightly weird is that the user id that works is about twice as long as the one that does not. The one that does not has 2FA turned on but I don't know if that is significant.

Comment: Could you specify where the User ID's came from? Did you test the app through the console simulator and get them there?

Comment: Yup. I viewed the simulator's request tab's dump of the JSON including the ID as authoritative and compared it to what I was getting at run time with app.getUser().userId. It was the latter that I passed to conversation API.